# Compiling specific files in a project in dev c++

Tags: compilation, dev-c++

I am writing a project on dev c++, that has a big number of files. However, the biggest part of them do not change every time I compile the code again, thus they do not have to be compiled again.

How can I compile only several files that I choose, and not the whole project?

Or is the compiler already doing it?

Will it help with compilation time?

*These are theoretical questions, I do not really mind waiting each time couple of seconds. It just got me interested.

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Compiling is a multistage process divided into two components: *compilation* and *linking*. Actully even if a program compiles fine it is not necessary that it work,because of the errors while linking. The total process of transformation from a source code to a object file can be termed as build.

**Compilation** refers to the processing of source code files (.c, .cc, or .cpp) and the creation of an 'object' file. The compiler merely produces the machine language instructions that correspond to the source code file that was compiled.This step doesn't create anything the user can actually run.

**Linking** refers to the creation of a single executable file from multiple object files. In this step, it is common that the linker will complain about undefined functions (commonly, main itself). So while compilation if the function is not defined in the current file ,it assumes that the function is declared somewhere else and the linker links the functions which is defined in other files

The compiler does its thing, and the linker does its thing -- by keeping the functions separate, the complexity of the program is reduced.The main advantage is that this allows the creation of large programs without having to redo the compilation step every time a file is changed. Instead, using *so called "**conditional compilation**", it is necessary to compile only those source files that have changed; for the rest, the object files are sufficient input for the linker. Finally, this makes it simple to implement libraries of pre-compiled code:*

If you're using an IDE this will be taken care for you defaultly and for command line tools, there's a nifty utility called make.